# Flutter web development server, serve JS file with wrong MIME type

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

I am trying to integrate firebase_messaging package on my web project.
On development server, I am getting error while generating firebase token

```
The script has an unsupported MIME type ('application/octet-stream').
 [firebase_messaging/failed-service-worker-registration] Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:19656/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:19656/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('application/octet-stream'). .
```

Cause of this error is wrong MIME type of .js file in development server.
But it work find when I release build on IIS.
As JS on IIS are serve with proper MIME type (text/javascript)